# Need to pass parameter from apex to controller in order to make dynamic url

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforcedx

```
<aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.displayAttach}"/> 
 <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
  fields="CaseNumber"
  />
    <center> 
        <lightning:button  onclick="{!c.handleClick}" label="Attach file">
        </lightning:button>
    </center>

  handleClick : function(component, event, helper){
    console.log('handleClick');
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
           console.log('Case number ====>'+ component.get("v.simpleRecord").CaseNumber);
     var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
     urlEvent.setParams({
         "url":  '/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid='+component.get("v.recordId")+'/parentname='+component.get("v.simpleRecord").CaseNumber+'/'+'&retURL=%2F'+component.get("v.recordId")         });
     urlEvent.fire();
},
```

on click of my lightning button I want to create a dynamic URL like this

> https://garvitasb2bsc--4hdev.cs60.my.salesforce.com/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid=5003C000003bdmt&parentname=0114054744&retURL=%2F5003C000003bdmtQAA where ‘500..’ is case id, ‘001’ is the case number.

I'm able to pass the case id I'm stuck how can I get case number

I'm getting this error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: c:CustomAttachmentRelatedList$controller$handleClick [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {c:CustomAttachmentRelatedList$controller$handleClick}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading a record using **force:recordData**? For example, you can put this markup on your lightning component and it should be able to load your data without using Apex at all. This feature is a part of the **Lightning Data Service**.

```
  <aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/>
  <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>

  <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
  fields="Subject,CaseNumber"
  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
  recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
  />

   "url": '/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid='+component.get("v.recordId")+'/parentname='component.get("v.simpleRecord.CaseNumber")+'/'+'&retURL=%2F'+component.get("v.recordId")
```

To access the record fields in the JavaScript controller, use the `component.get("v.simpleRecord.fieldName")` syntax. See [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_load_record.htm).

Comment: yes, I did this as well I'm getting the error I have updated the above code with comment @the_phantom

Comment: Are you using component.get("v.simpleRecord").CaseNumber? The CaseNumber field should be inside the parenthesis - component.get("v.simpleRecord.fieldName")

Comment: both will work component.get("v.simpleRecord").CaseNumber this and component.get("v.simpleRecord.fieldName") this as well but still I'm getting error  "Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {c:CustomAttachmentRelatedList$controller$handleClick}'

Comment: Try adding this dependency in the markup: <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToURL" type="EVENT"/>, refresh your browser multiple times and try again.

Comment: same error with this also